# Setting Up Rails 3.2.2 App on Heroku with sqlite3 locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I used Heroku in the past with Rails 3.0.9 using sqlite3 in development (locally).

database.yml

```
 development:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: /db/development.sqlite3
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000
```

Workflow as follows:

1. $ git init
2. $ add .
3. $ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
4. $ heroku create
5. $ git push heroku master
6. $ heroku rake db:migrate

...and I was off to the races, no problem.

Fast forward to today using Rails 3.2.2.  New very basic scaffold app, same database yml file, same workflow.  When using localhost:3000/addresses the index of addresses comes up no problem.  However, using the same workflow and step 6, heroku rake db:migrate, the rake aborted with the following error message:

```
      rake aborted!
      Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter`  (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

So I changed my gemfile to the following:

```
    group :Development, :test do
      gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    end

    group :Production do
      gem 'pg', '0.13.2'
    end
```

I then did a bundle install, committed my changes via git add . and git commit -m "Added pg" and pushed to heroku via git push heroku master.  Next I tried heroku rake db:migrate and the table was migrated.  However, when browsing to the app the default index page works, however, when trying the route HerokuInstanceName/addresses, I get the not so helpful error: "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Apologies for the long winded explanation, any ideas?

**Edit2:**The first route i missed typed as /address, here is the log file when I actually put in the correct route /addresses:

**Edit: added heroku log file:**

```
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /address] miss
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-window-3630.heroku.com/address  dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=728
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 86.163.131.200 - - [03/Apr/2012:22:05:41  +0000] "GET /address HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0" falling-window-3630.heroku.com
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-window-3630.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-04-03T22:05:41+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 86.163.131.200 - - [03/Apr/2012:22:05:41 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0" falling-window-3630.heroku.com
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/addresses" for 86.163.131.200 at   2012-04-03 15:05:45 -0700
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AddressesController#index as HTML
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered addresses/index.html.erb within   layouts/application (15.0ms)
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 91ms
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2192528381921801676_29536600'
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>HavenCollect2</title>
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /addresses] miss
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-window-3630.heroku.com/addresses dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=145ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-04-03T22:05:45+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 86.163.131.200 - - [03/Apr/2012:22:05:45 +0000] "GET /addresses HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0" falling-window-3630.heroku.com
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/addresses" for [local ip address] at      2012-04-03 15:32:50 -0700
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AddressesController#index as HTML
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered addresses/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>HavenCollect2</title>
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2192528381921801676_29536600'
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /addresses] miss
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-window-3630.heroku.com/addresses dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-04-03T22:32:50+00:00 heroku[nginx]: [local ip address] - - [03/Apr/2012:22:32:50 +0000] "GET /addresses HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19" falling-window-3630.heroku.com
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AddressesController#index as HTML
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/addresses" for [local ip address] at 2012-04-03 15:32:56 -0700
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-window-3630.heroku.com/addresses dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=15ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>HavenCollect2</title>
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered addresses/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: [local ip address] - - [03/Apr/2012:22:32:56 +0000] "GET /addresses HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19" falling-window-3630.heroku.com
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2192528381921801676_29536600'
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /addresses] miss
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/addresses" for [local ip address] at     2012-04-03 15:32:59 -0700
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AddressesController#index as HTML
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered addresses/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>HavenCollect2</title>
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </head>
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2192528381921801676_29536600'
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /addresses] miss
2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-window-3630.heroku.com/addresses dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=643
```

2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 heroku[nginx]: [local ip address] - - [03/Apr/2012:22:32:59 +0000] "GET /addresses HTTP/1.1" 500 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19" falling-window-3630.heroku.com

- Removed First Log File

Comment: Try to access that same page and after you get that error page, go to your console and enter `heroku logs`. What's the issue?

Comment: I added log file but didn't see anything that provided a clue.

Comment: Well, it appears you have a routing error. `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/address"):`

Comment: The first route i missed typed as /address instead of /addresses, I replaced the log file above.

Comment: What heroku stack are you on? Unless you're using cedar, you need to precompile your assets.

Comment: fatfrog, It's on bamboo-mri-1.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2012-04-03T22:32:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):

Try

bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Git add .

Push

If you upgrade to the cedar stack you don't need to precompile your assets.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar